# How to manage the installation and configuration of software on non-domain joined Windows XP machines?

Tags: windows-xp, monitoring, configuration-management

I have a large set of unattended Windows XP machines who are not connected to a domain or even to each other.  I am struggling to find any tools out there that I can use to deal with them in one application.

I am hoping to find software that I can perhaps install a client on each machine, then have it essentially proxy out configuration information and possibly commands (install, uninstall, stop service, etc) across the whole network.

The closest I've come is Nagios and its client, but it cannot be used to push files through and run commands remotely.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question was more about a combination monitoring and software management solution.  We have a method for installing software alone, but we are looking for a more full featured solution that can can alert us when the installed software changes or the cpu is maxed out.

Answer (score 2):

This is what domains are for.

Alternative:
if computers are all the same (like computer lab)
could use disk/file-system cloning (e.g. Ghost)

Answer (score 1):

Ghost or similar imaging tools are fine for making changes to one system, and then applying those changes to others through reformatting and such, but I'd consider WPKG as well.

From [their overview page](http://wpkg.org/WPKG_overview):

- fully automated software deployment
  solution for Windows
- deploy software
  in any format - MSI, EXE, etc.
- deploy
  software to different groups of
  computers or single workstations
- easily install, upgrade or remove
  software
- a "pull" psexec equivalent
- run custom scripts to set printers,
  synchronize time, manipulate
  permissions, add registry entries,
  [change Windows settings](http://wpkg.org/Category:Changing_Windows_settings) etc.
- management/administration of end-user
  workstations
- WPKG works in a domain,
  in a workgroup, or even over the
  Internet or VPN (no domain controller
  needed)
- WPKG works with Linux
  (Samba), Windows servers, or any
  other systems supporting Windows
  Network Neighborhood
- WPKG works with
  Windows 2000, XP Pro/Home, 2003 and
  Vista clients, but also 9x and Me
  (selected functions only)

I'm working on setting up WPKG for in-domain software deployment currently. For making consistent settings across a group of systems, I'd still never give up a proper domain with Group Policy and Group Policy Preferences, but if you can't afford that for whatever reason, WPKG is worth a shot.